# What are other ways to describe second-last?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Actually, I'm not even sure if the *"second-last"* is the correct term. Here is how I would use it:

> Go down the hallway, it's the second-last door on your right.

which I want to describe the door that is immediately next to the last door.

What are other ways to describe it?
Can I say, e.g., *next-last*?

Also, how about the one that next to second-last? Can I say third-last?

**EDIT:** broadening the usage, can I say "this is the *next-best* choice"? Are there any other ways to express it?

Thanks

Comment: Easy answer- yes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @MaulikV's answer that "second-to-last" is a natural way to describe it; "next-to-last" would also be perfectly normal and possibly even more common.

Other ways to describe it would be to say "last-but-one" or something like "6th out of 7."

To answer your "broadened usage" question, yes, you can go from *best* to *next-best* or *second-best*; in these cases, the preposition *to* is not required (indeed, it must be omitted).

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer, Hellion. Maybe you want to move the controversy of whether "second-to-last" is the same as "next-to-last" to the comment section for a clear answer, as most people disagree with the argument.

Comment: Fair enough... There are some people out there who believe that "second-to-last" is not the same as "next-to-last".  (I, and I think most people, disagree with them, but I know they're out there, having argued this point with them at least once.)  In their minds the final three spots would go "second-to-last, next-to-last, last."

Answer (score 3):

- The last room is the **ultimate** room.
- The next-to-last room is the **pen**ultimate room.
- The next-to-next-to-last room is **ante**penultimate room.
- The next-to-next-to-next-to-last room is the **pre**antepenultimate room.

You do have to be careful with context though, as ultimate could also be taken as the "best" choice. The *ultimate* vacation would be the best vacation, not the worst.

Comment: No one talks like that.

Comment: I don't think it's common, but penultimate comes in handy for exactly the situation asked about.

Comment: @relaxing, I have had occasion to say *antepenultimate*, but I've never tried to load any more prefixes on than that.

Comment: Do people say *penultimate best*?

Comment: @xpt I suppose you could, but it sounds awkward.

Comment: @xpt - Both *second best* and *next best* work, but neither "ultimate best" nor "penultimate best" work.

Answer (score 1):

You may go for *[second-to-last](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/second-to-last)*. Note, the *to* is added there.

The single word for that is: penultimate (but I agree with *relaxing!*)

> [penultimate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penultimate) - occurring immediately before the last one

Just a concern, if you are describing the rooms in a series, aren't they numbered?

**The edit after OP's comment:**

Since you described the scenario where the rooms are not numbered and even if they are, how to say it? I think it's all about *lessening the efforts* to find the exact room, isn't it?.

Now, suppose if you 20 rooms in a row, I'd prefer telling him the *6th room* on your right over *X-to-last*. The finder does not have to go to the last room and come backward. Instead, he'll start counting and stop right in front of the 5th room! This way, we save his efforts of finding *non numbered* or *numbered* room. Note that as the order of the room number gets closer to 20, our term *penultimate*, *third-to-last* comes into the picture.

Comment: *"you said immediately next to last; what you mean? "* I meant next-to-last. The *immediately* was just to emphasize.

Comment: @xpt The word in concern is **next** (bolded) and not *immediately!* That's because *next* is moving further - left to right or in such order.

Comment: Since there is nothing *after* the last, "Next to last" is clearly and unambiguously referring to the one *before* the last....

Comment: @Hellion I firmly believed that *next* is always advancing but *before your comment.* :D Thanks. Answer edited.

Comment: If we are in a line (standing side-to-side, not front-to-back), and I am standing next to you, am I before or after you?  *Next* can be referring to sequence, as you originally assumed, or merely to position.  :-)  (Generally, a "sequential next" will either stand alone ("the next person") or with an *in* ("the next in line"), while a "positional next" will have a *to* ("he stood next to me", "it is next to last").

Comment: *"Just a concern, if you are describing the rooms in a series, aren't they numbered?"* Yes and no, what if I'm describing the next-to-last room in my own house? Also, here is another example: Question: "Where is room #1215"? Answer: "Go down the hallway this way, it's the next-to-last room on your right"

Comment: @Hellion True. I learned this and will remember now onward! :) Thank you.